# Find circle for two points, one with given angle.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, circles, geometric-construction

I have point A and B. I also have a vector v.
How can I mathematically find a circle whose tangent at point C has the same angle as v where point C is the same as B and the circle also contains point A.

Here is an illustration:
[image: Illustration]

Black dot is A
Red dot is B
Orange arrow is vector v
Green circle is on both A and B, while one of it's tangents is on v.
Black line is the tangent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The center is equidistant from $A$ and $B$, so it lies on the perpendicular bisector of these two points.  Call the bisector $\ell_1$

Any radius is perpendicular to a tangent vector.  So, the center lies on a line through $B$ perpendicular to the tangent.  Call this second line $\ell_2$.

The center of the circle must be at the (generally uniquely existent) intersection of lines $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$.  The radius of the circle is simply the distance from this point (the center) to either $A$ or $B$.